# postgresql 12: array to column

Tags: sql, jsonb, postgresql-12

I have a table similar to

| product | quantity A | quantity B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| product 1 | [2] | [1,2] |
| product 2 | [null] | [4] |

and would like to change that into the following table:

| product | quantity A_1 | quantity B_1 | quantity B_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| product 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| product 2 | null | 4 | null |

I.e. into a table in which the columns "quantity A" and "quantity B" are divided into as many columns as necessary in order for them to contain only one element.

Atm, the type of the columns "quantity A" and "quantity B" is `jsonb`. Among other ideas, I considered transforming the `jsonb arrays` into `jsonb objects`, but don't know how to deal with the variable number of elements in the `json arays`.
Consulting https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html I don't real find a solution.

Does somebody have any ideas?

Comment: Have no idea how this would be useful. You will not be able to reference automatically generated columns, because you do not know, if the column `quantity B_3` exists. You have to query the information schema tables to know.

Comment: This would be much easier with a properly normalized data model. Having a table with one column per product is a big mistake to begin with. What if you have thousands if not millions of products? And then storing multiple values inside a single column is another bad design choice.

Comment: In general this is not possible. The number of columns of a query must be known _before_ the query is executed. Also: what would you want to get if you have thousands of elements in each array?

Comment: Well, the first table is already processed (a lot) and the number of elements within one array is not expected to be a large number. It's rather around 3.
The motivation to do this, is that people want to have it like this in an Excel document.